# Eclipse can't resolve transitive dependency projects?

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation, compiler-errors

In a Java project in Eclipse, I am trying to debug project A.

Project `A` has a dependency on `B.jar`, normally `B.jar` comes from my `.m2/repository`.
but now I want to make some temp changes to `B`'s code, and have it reflected in `A`,
so I directly edit the source code in `B` project in eclipse, and set `B` as a dependency project in `A`'s build path. Additionally, both `A` and `B` refer to `C.jar` as their dependencies.

This builds `A` fine, but when it is run, `A`'s `classpath` contains 2 copies of all the classes and resources in `C.jar`. this creates a problem for those hibernate `hbm.xml` mapping files in `C.jar` and I got errors saying `duplicate mapping for...`

This looks to be a defect in eclipse, in that it lacks the resolution ability as maven posseses. is there a way to work around this? (apart from building B and installing to .m2 instead of having it as a dependency project)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "[setting] B as a dependency project in A's build path" - do you mean editing eclipse's build path or editing the project's POM? I'm guessing the former, in which case make sure that you have the latest version of the m2eclipse plugin installed and that both projects `A` & `B` are Maven eclipse projects. If it is set up correctly then your projects should look have an 'M' on their project icons, and the icons of any workspace dependencies should look like folders.

Comment: Thanks, I mean the former (editing eclipse build path). I started with m2eclipse, and failed, and thought that might be the reason, but tried plain eclipse without m2eclipse, still fails the same. let me try updating m2eclipse

Comment: hmmm doesn't seem to work, updated to   'M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse (Incubation) 0.13.0.201105261543 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group'  still the same problems

Comment: Did you make sure that eclipse recognises them as Maven projects? If they aren't so already, right-click on their project icons in the package explorer pane and select 'Configure' -> 'Convert to Maven Project'. Would be best to back up those projects and/or label them in your source control before doing so because it's hard to reverse if it goes wrong. You might want to create a couple of Maven projects via 'New' -> 'Project...' -> 'Maven' - > 'Maven Project' and have one reference the other in its POM - that way you can see what it should looks like when it's all working.

Comment: yeah, I did make sure they are maven projects. "Maven" --> "disable maven nature", then again "configure"--> convert to  maven project. thanks a lot

Comment: Is project C a Maven project as well? If so, do the dependency declarations of C in A & B's POMs specify the same version? The only way I can think of ending up with 2 copies of that jar in the build is if A & B are using different versions of C.

Comment: thanks, C is just a jar, not having a project in eclipse. yeah the version could be a problem, let me check that